# How to Open PDF File Stored in MySQL Table Using an Anchor Tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdf

I am trying to use PHP to create a link that opens a PDF file from my MySQL DB table. The PDF file is already stored in the Sql table I am just not sure how to open it with an anchor tag.

The PDF is called "a26ea542-b307-4cd6-9f62-7ba04831a0f1.pdf".

Here is my PHP page code:

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM `file`';
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);

// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
    // Make sure there are some files in there
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
    }
    else {
        // Print the top of a table
        echo '<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                    <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                    <td><b>Created</b></td>
                    <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                </tr>';

        // Print each file
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['size']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                    <td><a href='{$row['name']}'>Open</a></td>
                </tr>";
        }

        // Close table
        echo '</table>';
    }

    // Free the result
    $result->free();
}
else
{
    echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
    echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
}

// Close the mysql connection
$dbLink->close();
?>
```

Thank you, for any help. I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overall plan**

Using a PHP script `A.php`, generate an HTML-page, which includes links to another script `someScript.php`. This second script generates the PDF.

To link to page 3 of the PDF generated by `someScript.php`, use links like this one:

- `http://myServ.com/someScript.php#page=3`

Replace myServ.com with the DNS name of your server.

**Sending a PDF to the browser**

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('a26ea542-b307-4cd6-9f62-7ba04831a0f1.pdf');
```

**Linking to portions of the PDF**

Points to a **page of the pdf**:

```
<a href="http://myServ.com/someScript.php#page=3">
   Points to page 3
</a>
```

Assign markers using Adobe Acrobat and **point to them**:

```
<a href="http://myServ.com/someScript.php#nameddest=Marker3">
  Point to Marker3
</a>
```

Comment: The PDF is stored in a MySQL Database, not in my FTP Server.

Comment: @Michael I'm aware of that!

Comment: My PHPmyAdmin URL is cp.freehostia.com, do I use this to replace http://myServ.com?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this instead?

```
<a href='http://www.website-url.com/FolderName/{$row['name']}' > Open </a>
```

Folder Name is where your pdf file is stored.

I assumed that {$row['name']} is just the file name of your pdf.

Comment: The PDF file is not stored in a folder. It is stored in my website's MySQL Database. I do not want to use folders, thank you though.